# How to retrieve values from a MultiCheckbox in ZF2

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

How do you retrieve each selected value from a MultiCheckbox element in a ZF2 form?  I’ve set up the following code:

```
/ ... /

$myMultiCheckbox = new Element\MultiCheckbox('my-multicheckbox');
$myMultiCheckbox->setValueOptions(array(
   '1' => 'option1',
   '2' => 'option2',
   '3' => 'option3',
   '4' => 'option4',
   '5' => 'option5',
   '6' => 'option6',
));

/ ... /

$request = $this->getRequest();
$mySelections = $request->getPost('my-multicheckbox');

/ ... /
```

If only one option gets selected, `$mySelections` returns the proper value.  If two or more options get selected, my expectation is that `$mySelections` and array of selected options.  Instead, `$mySelections`  returns the last (or highest) value.

I’ve also tried:

```
/ ... /

$request = $this->getRequest();
$mySelections = $myMultiCheckbox->getValue();

/ ... /
```

but this returns an empty result that is not an array.

Comment: `$element->getValue()` should return an array of all the selected values. If this is not the case check that the element markup has the correct `multiple="multiple"` when rendered.

Comment: @AlexP Which element should have `multiple="multiple"` when rendered? Both `formRow` and `formMultiCheckbox` render `<label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="my-multicheckbox[]"></input>option1</label>` for each of the options, without any other container element.